# Static File in public/ is not serving(displaying) properly when I deploy on Server with Nginx, Node Express EJS

Tags: node.js, express, nginx, ejs

Hi smart people out there!
I need some help...(I am novice on deploying on VPS so any help would be appreciated!)

I have built a website with nodejs express and ejs. It is all working good in my local machine.
However the problem coming up when I deploy on VPS server with Nginx as reverse proxy.

The problem I am having is that I can connect using IP address provided by VPS but it seems like files in public/ folder is not parsing on browser.
In my public folder it has js/ , css/ and image/ directories.

This is my /etc/nginx/sites-available/my_website_folder_name

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name my_IP_address; #at the moment I am just checking to see if all working fine

   location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    }

}
```

with this setting, the static file is not displaying and also I can't open any files with URL address as below.

```
http://my_IP_address/assets/images/samplePhoto.png
```

But if I add this line to /etc/nginx/sites-available/my_website_folder_name

```
   location /assets {
        root /var/www/my_site_folder/public;
   }
```

then I can at least can open the photo with URL address but still static files are not displaying..
so css, js and iimage files not applied. If I inspect from Chrome development tool, the element showing all good.

Can anyone help ? If need I will update more files as requested.. I have read all I can find form online and wasn't working..

This is setting from app.js

```
app.engine('ejs', ejsMate)
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'))

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')))
```